# Help get me a grand piano Hi Gloss Finish please

Tags: furniture

[image]

Hi everyone 
My carpenter friend has made me this mini grand piano shell for my one keyboard and I want to get it painted or sprayed like a grand piano finish.
I'm a complete novice here and need every assistance like what paint to use? Do I want an epoxy resin etc
Any help really appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a water white conversion varnish for years with very excellent results.  it must be applied with a sprayer and dries very quickly so multiple coats can be applied.  I get my sprayer gun at harbor freight for $10-$14.  Conversion varnish is a catalyzed product that can easily be buffed out once it is cured.  Check out Lenmar Megavar.  Excellent stuff.  Once cured, use a buffer with 3M Perfect-It 05973.  Epoxy would be impossible to apply to vertical surfaces and it's much more expensive. I believe you would be well served by using this process.